# How to calculate the integral with the condition in wolfram

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

How to calculate the integral with the condition in Wolfram like

> Integral(1/(x^4 + y^4)dxdy) where y >=x^2+1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the definite integral over all x, y>x^2+1. The syntax is this:

```
Integrate[1/(x^4 + y^4), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},{ y, x^2 + 1,Infinity}]
```

Note mathematica's ordering of the integration variables is reverse of standard convention, ie. left to right is outside to inside.  This takes quite a while to report that it does not converge. However the numerical integration gives a result:

```
NIntegrate[1/(x^4 + y^4), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},{ y, x^2 + 1,Infinity}]
```

> 0.389712

My guess is the numeric result is correct and mathematica is simply wrong about the analytic convergence. You might try math.stackexchange.com or mathematica.stackexchange.com if you need to prove convergence. I am doubtful there is a nice analytic result.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Integrate[1/(x^4 + y^4), y, x, Assumptions -> y >= x^2 + 1]
```

note also [Multiple Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultipleIntegral.html)